# Can´t load a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested-loops

The first for loop seems to be executed just one time, while the second (inner) for loop works fine.
I tried every type of loop I know but always got the same result.
I normally don´t have these problems with loops so I´m quite curious to what the problem might be.

```
    public class xirtam {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {

                int max_columns = 10;
                int max_characters_in_a_column = 30, sign;
                int array[][] = new int[max_columns][max_characters_in_a_column];


                for(int y=0;y<=max_columns;y++) {  

> // This loop seems to be executed just 1 time


                    for (int x=0 ; x<=max_characters_in_a_column ; x++) {  

> //This loop works fine for some reason


                        sign = (int) (Math.random() * ((256 - 0) + 1));

                        array[y][x] = sign;

                        System.out.println("column " + y + " character " + x + ":"+ array[y][x]); // prints out the "column" and "character" where the loop is currently working

                        //Thread.sleep(100);
                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for supressing all Exceptions ?

Comment: Not really, I asked classmates and friends and they told me to try to suppress the Exceptions to see what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 30 out of bounds for length 30` at `array[y][x] = sign;`. That is why.

In your second for loop use `x<max_characters_in_a_column` not `<=`. This will solve your issue. And the same for the first loop, also.

The maximum indexing for your array will be `array[9][29]`, as you have defined the dimensions as 10 and 30.